# double free or corruption (!prev) c++ opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, free, corruption

I'm implementing a method that decomposes the images,it takes an image as input and returns many images as output called BEMCs.Here is my main function where I try to return just the first BEMC :

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
if (argc != 2) {
    std::cout << "Usage: ./emd <image>" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
cv::Mat inputImg;
cv::Mat imgMode;

inputImg=imread(argv[1],CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); 

if(! inputImg.data )                             
{   cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
    return -1;
}
namedWindow("Source Image",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("Source Image",inputImg);
cv::waitKey(1000);

Mat gray;
cvtColor(inputImg,gray,COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Mat grayy;
gray.convertTo(grayy, CV_32F);
sprintf(modeTitle, "BEMC-%d", 1);
std::cout << "Decomposition " << modeTitle << std::endl;
cv::Mat imgMod(grayy) , result;

imgMod = decompose(grayy); *************main.cpp:387********                                                 
//**** decompose is the function that generate the error******
...........................
...........................
}
```

Here's a portion of my function decompose,first I'm trying to find maximas of the image ,then I'm trying to store them into vectors that I use to do other things:

```
cv::Mat decompose(cv::Mat input )
{
cv::Mat inputImg;
input.copyTo(inputImg);

std::vector<Euclidean> vectEMax, vectEMin;

cv::Mat imgMax;
...................................
vectEMax.push_back(max);vectEMax.push_back(min);

 ................................

 std::vector<Euclidean>::iterator it1, it2;

 ..............................
```

I'm using the iteretors to calculate distances between maximas,all these operations work fine,I insert the elements in vectEMax and calculate without any problems. At the end of the program I have to return an image as a result of the method .

```
    cv::Mat  imgMoyenne //imgMoyenne is an image based on maximas,calculted  
                         in the program
    ....................
    cv::Mat diff_im;
    inputImg.copyTo(diff_im);
    diff_im = inputImg - imgMoyenne ;
    return diff_im;}*****************main.cpp:345**************
```

The program crashes after the return,it shows

*** glibc detected *** ./gdb_core: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x08c33d78 ***

here is a gdb output

```
  Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
  #0  0xb7738424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()

  thread apply all bt

 Thread 1 (Thread 0xb4282740 (LWP 3652)):
 #0  0xb773a424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
 #1  0xb6f1f1df in __GI_raise (sig=6)
 at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
 #2  0xb6f22825 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:91
 #3  0xb6f5c39a in __libc_message (do_abort=2, 
 fmt=0xb70578e8 "*** glibc detected *** %s: %s: 0x%s ***\n")
 at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/libc_fatal.c:201
 #4  0xb6f66ee2 in malloc_printerr (action=<optimized out>, 
 str=<optimized out>, ptr=0x8c33d78) at malloc.c:5039
#5  0xb7549c22 in cv::fastFree(void*) ()
from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4
#6  0xb763e78b in cv::Mat::deallocate() ()
from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4
#7  0x0804c1fd in cv::Mat::release (this=0xbfda1fc8)
at /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:367
#8  0x0804c055 in cv::Mat::~Mat (this=0xbfda1fc8, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
at /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:276
#9  0x0804b24c in decompose (input=...) at main.cpp:345
#10 0x0804b87f in main (argc=2, argv=0xbfda25a4) at main.cpp:387
```

I need your help please

Comment: It looks like `diff_im` is being created on the stack, and therefore it won't be available outside the function it was created in. Instead, you should create `diff_im` on the heap using the `new` operator, and then return a pointer to it.

Comment: or change you function to something like: `void decompose(cv::Mat input, cv::Mat& output)`

Comment: @pgngp thank you for your reply ,I created diff_im like that `cv::Mat* diff = new cv::Mat(inputImg- imgMoyenne);` , I changed the return type of method to `cv::Mat* decompose(cv::Mat input)` and `cv::Mat* imgMod = new cv::Mat(grayy); imgMod = decompose(grayy); (main function) ` but I still have the same error

Comment: @incBrain thank you for your reply, I tried this method before and also now after your suggestion but I still have the same error.

Comment: @ImaneEL: You mentioned that you created `diff_im` like `cv::Mat* diff = new cv::Mat(inputImg- imgMoyenne);` in which the pointer name is `diff` and not `diff_im`. You hopefully used the correct name in the return statement, right?

Comment: @pgngp I'm sorry, I misspoke I created a pointer `diff` and I returned  `diff`

Comment: Is there a way I can see your updated whole code? Debugging will be easier that way.

Comment: @pgngp this is the whole code http://www.sendbox.fr/f2937dc40f407318/main.cpp  http://www.sendbox.fr/686a5f1c3b35dfb7/Euclidean.cpp  http://www.sendbox.fr/65f949a2c07fc418/Euclidean.hpp

Comment: @ImaneEL please use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) for uploading code.

Comment: @ImaneEL I'm trying to run your code on my computer. Do you have the `Euclidean.cpp` file? How long does it take for the program to run and throw the error?

Comment: @incBrain  http://pastebin.com/mWanGMbf                                                                   http://pastebin.com/Ph7Mb6yf                                                                          http://pastebin.com/KrKEw9WA

Comment: @pgngp here's my Euclidean.cpp http://pastebin.com/Ph7Mb6yf                                                     Euclidean.hpp http://pastebin.com/KrKEw9WA                                       The program takes 1 or 2 minutes for an image of 128x128

Comment: @ImaneEL I see a `MAX` function being used within `decompose` function. Where is this `MAX` function defined?

Comment: @pgngp it's defined in the beginning of main.cpp line 26

Comment: It was commented out, so that's why I got confused.

Comment: @pgngp thank you for your replies . I commented out the line just to try something but normally it's not a comment I forgot to remove the //

Comment: @ImaneEL I think the problem is in lines 92 and 93 in main.cpp (http://pastebin.com/mWanGMbf). The problem is that `k` might have a value >= `inputImg.rows` and `l` might have a value >= `inputImg.cols`. To prevent this from happening, you need to have `k < i + SIZ && k < inputImg.rows;` and `l < j + SIZ && k < inputImg.cols;` in rows 92 and 93, respectively.

Comment: @pgngp Thank you very much for the help,The error message is gone but the result is empty , I tested ` diff ` before returning the result ,it contains data but after this ligne ` imgMod = decompose(grayy); ` imgmod is empty  `imgMode.rows= 0 imgMode.cols= 0 `

Comment: The return value of `decompose(grayy);` is being stored in `imgMod`, but you are not using `imgMod` after that line. You are instead using `imgMode`, which is empty.

Comment: @pgngp you're right, my program works now.Thank you for taking the time to solve my problem ...great thanks!

Comment: That's great to know!

Comment: @pgngp ,I just want to tell you that the program crahses `SOMETIMES` ,it shows  this error ` *** glibc detected *** ./gdb_core: free(): invalid pointer` and gdb indicates this line `newImgMax.at<float>(l,k) = sum(imgMax,l, k, wmax)/(wmax*wmax);` line 276 of main.cpp [link] http://pastebin.com/mWanGMbf

Comment: Did you step into the `sum` function and see where the error is occuring? I suspect that the error is occurring somewhere inside the `sum` function; probably you are accessing a memory location in the `img` object that is out-of-bounds.

Comment: @pgngp okay I'm checking the calculations and I will focus on the method "sum"

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while but I have just had the exact same error. I found out what line of my code triggered it by commenting block by block.

It is with the `cv::Mat::copyTo()` method. It will trigger the same error if you use `cv::Mat::clone()` instead. I got rid of it because I did not really need a deep copy.

I do not have the underlying explanation to why this is happening. If you inspect the error message, it says things about freeing the memory but OpenCV should take care of that.